# How this loader inside a black background

Tags: css

I am trying to show the loader inside a black background of border radius 50px at the center of the screen which it already is.
How do I do it ?
I have given it position fixed so that it remain at the same place even if the page is scrolled. Only thing I need is that the logo should be inside the black background all above the overlay.

It should be at the middle of the black background from all sides.

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 220px;
  z-index: 999999999999 !important;
}
.loader img:before{
  background: color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
   z-index: 99999999 !important;
    width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
  left: 0;
   right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 6;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <div class="overlay"></div><div class="loader text-center"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5fcCZ8G.gif"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You question is not very clear. You have already specified `background-color: #000;` in `.overlay` class. It might not be appearing as black since you have also given `opacity: 0.3`. If you set `opacity` as `1`, your background will become black. Is this what you needed?

Comment: did you see the typo in ```background: color: black;```? Should be ```background-color: black;```.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `opacity` for overlay div and `background: color:` is not supported. use `background-color:`
Reference: https://cssreference.io/property/background-color/

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 220px;
  z-index: 999999999999 !important;
}
.loader img:before{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
   z-index: 99999999 !important;
    width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
  left: 0;
   right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 6;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <div class="overlay"></div><div class="loader text-center"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5fcCZ8G.gif"></div>
</div>
```